# How to source a makefile from another makefile?

Tags: makefile

In other words, how to get a similar effect to that of `.` (dot) in bash or `execfile` in python in make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `include` directive:

```
include the-other-makefile
```

Reasonable ways in which you could have discovered this without asking it:

- read POSIX 7 http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html "Include Lines" (not present in 6 it seems)
- by reading [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/makefile/makefile_directives.htm) from beginning to end before asking anything
- by looking at the table of contents of [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/makefile/makefile_directives.htm) and knowing beforehand that you are probably looking for a so called *directive* (include is a directive)
- guess that instead of `source` as in bash, it could be called `include` as in c, and then search for the `include` keyword in the [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)
- read the entire table of contents for the and deduce that `include` does what you need

Comment: This is a GNU make extension and only works with GNU make, not other makes.  For BSD make, you need to use `.include "filename"`.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I checked [POSIX 7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html#tag_20_76_13_02) and it seemed to me that include lines can do the same as the GNU version... but it is a bit hard to read and maybe I got it wrong. There is also the question if that part of the standard is widely followed or not.

Comment: @ChrisDodd also I tried include that with a `.POSIX` special target and it worked. Might of course be a problem on the gnu implementation of `.POSIX`, or good old unspecified behavior.

Comment: First, the latest POSIX standards do indeed define `include`.  This was added fairly recently; it's not present in Issue 6 (2004) but is present in the current Issue 7.  Second, declaring the `.POSIX:` target does _NOT_ mean that any makefile which is not POSIX-conforming will fail.  It just means that if you have a POSIX-conforming makefile (which by definition must declare `.POSIX:`) then it will succeed.

Comment: @MadScientist I read the manual you seem right about `.POSIX`, take back what I said about it.